# Preparing a page in Printer Version to be saved locally with browser "save page as..." (no server-side scripting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, save

I am working on an HTML page (no server-side scripting) web page with JavaScript.
That has to be modified dynamically by the user. Then I want to let the user save this page locally as a .html file.

> To achieve this, I suggest the user to use **the browser function "Save
>   page as..."**.

I do that because I want the user to have complete local access to this file when off-line.

The question is that I would like the user to save the page  **in Printer Version** after I have hidden all the stuff he does not need (menus, instructions, etc.).
I have already linked the css stylesheet for printing (with "media=print") and I would like to use it to change the aspect of the page before the user save it.
(It's not possible to use an iFrame because the browser function "Save page as..." saves always an entire page.)

> I ask if anybody know a way to **link dynamically a new
>   css-stylesheet to the page**  that will replace the css style hiding
>   the unwanted css classes.

The solution must work in recent versions of browsers, not old.

Comment: $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');

Comment: @artm - Yes, thanks! it works very well! I append my printer.css and it's all. Is a very clean way to show a print preview I think. But why you did'nt put it like an answer?

Comment: Wasn't 100 % sure if it would work for you, I added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new style sheet with your print rules to your document as such when needed;

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="printerFriedly.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. And if anybody want to restore the page, I only suggest to remove the link. It will be easier if you put before a id in the link: append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="printerFriedly.css" type="text/css" id="save_preview" />')     and so: $('#save_preview').remove();